# Make content be aware of the section

Tags: 7

I have a site divided by in multiple section which are actually some taxonomy views (taxonomy/term/term_ID).

It works like this:

- I have some specific blocks for each section.
- Content can be found in multiple sections

The problem is that (because the node is part of multiple section) I don't know how to display the same blocks on the node page as the ones in the section the user just left.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [contextpphp](http://drupal.org/project/contextphp) module and adding a SESSSION variable as a reaction to each section. Then checked this variable as a condition for another context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module and create two different contexts by adding conditions as path.

Enable the reactions as blocks and add same blocks in different sections using two context that you created !

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.

Hope it solves the problem :-)

Comment: The question was about the context module.